# How do I add the storm mongo library as a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, apache-storm

I'm trying to use a SimpleMongoBolt from [storm-contrib](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib). I downloaded the source, entered the storm-contrib-mongo directory and ran mvn package and mvn install. Everything worked fine and IntelliJ was able to resolve things while coding. When I try to build my project, however, it tries to find a pom for this library on an external repository. When it can't find it, it fails. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>StormTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>StormTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>StormTest</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
            <scope>Test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rapportive</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-amqp-spout</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rapportive</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-contrib-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure you've installed those dependencies into your local repository? Could you check the `~/.m2` repository if they are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleMongoBolt in Storm-Contrib was actually out of date. I updated the module myself and submitted a pull request, which has yet to be merged. Currently you can retrieve the updated code from [my Storm-Contrib fork](https://github.com/ilionblaze/storm-contrib).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check if you have proper dependencies defined in your project pom and compare them to storm artifact one. *groupId*, *artifactId* and *version* must be the same or Maven will try to download it from external repository and probably failed as it has never been installed on any public Maven repo.

When you install your artifact, it goes to *user-directory*/.m2/repostiory/*group/id/path*/*artifact/id/path*/*version*.

For your storm-amqp-spout you should have it in:
***user-directory*/.m2/repository/com/rapportive/storm-amqp-spout/0.1.1** folder.

There you should have few files:

1. *jar* itself (if it was packaged as jar file).
2. *pom.xml* file (the same you created for your project and you used to built and install it).
3. optionally *sha1* files for both above.

If you don't have them, you probably made some mistake installing the artifact into repository. You can try to install it again or manually create pom just copying it from artifact source directory.

If there's correct pom.xml, I don't really have idea as I have never worked with IntelliJ (idea? ;)).